# insert data in multiple tables in one mysql query

Tags: mysql, insert

Suppose there are two tables e1 and e2 with

```
e1
|id |time     | ca| cb|
|1  | 12:20:00| 5 | 10|
|2  | 12:25:00| 9 | 6 |
```

and:

e2

```
|id| time    | cc|   
|1 | 12:20:00| 11|  
|2 | 12:25:00| 50|
```

Now I want to insert third record ine1 and e2 having id:3 and store id,time in both table and ca,cb in e1 and cc in e2.it should be perform in single query.

e1

```
|id | time       |  ca|   cb  |
|1  |  12:20:00  |  5 |   10  |
|2  | 12:25:00   |  9 |   6   |
|**3|   12:28:00 |  11|    7**|
```

and:

e2

```
id| time      |  cc|   
|1|  12:20:00 |  11|  
|2|   12:25:00|  50|
|**3| 12:28:00|  23**|
```

whether its possible ?I am novice to MySQL

Comment: [insert syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) quite clear, there is only one `tbl_name`. SQL normalization is about only storing data once. You use queries to with joins/filters form the end result.

Comment: There is a couple of solutions. Stored procedure is preferred. Smart trigger may be used, of course, but it is "bad practice".

Comment: how to do it through stored procedure ? @Akina

Comment: Can you help me how to do query with joins/filter since I am new mysql .and there is two table .i want to insert values in two tables .

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to provide *the appearance of* "should be performed in single query".  What is your goal behind requesting such?

**Data integrity**  (see "ACID")

There are cases where you 'must' tie two inserts together, else the integrity of the database is in question.  The classic example is moving money from one account to another, but that usually involves a single table.

```
 BEGIN;
 UPDATE ... take money out of one person's account
 UPDATE ... add that money to another person's account
 COMMIT;
```

Whether the same table or different tables are involved, the above *guarantees* that *both* operations will be done *or* neither will be done.  The "money" won't vanish even if there is a power failure at any time during the "transaction".

Is that what you need for "inserting into two table at the same time"?  A transaction can, and should, be used for any set of writes to table(s) in database(s) (on a single instance of MySQL) where the writes must be done "at the same time".

**Programming**

Akina suggests using a Stored Procedure as a way to programmatically wrap the sequence of events, thereby giving the user the appearance of a "single operation":

```
CALL Transfer(acct1, acct2, amount);
```

Comment: my goal is use sql library directly as it will take less time instead of using mysql query in php as it takes more time.

Comment: How much slower is it?

Comment: it is slower by 2 3 secs.we want to use for realtime data .is it possible to do such query ? if not possible then I will call the two query separately .and same thing I want for reading also.to read diffrent data from diff table with one mysql query .

Comment: @Kajal - Please provide the specific SQLs involved, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the two tables.